# Intellij IDEA : Отказано в доступе

Tags: java

Привет! В II показывает вот эту ошибку, мол отказано в доступе. Пробовал удалить - не пускает: нету прав.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуй оставить процесс google drive. Видимо данный файл используется им.

Comment: Спасибо. В этом была причина.